# Bootstrap modal window is getting opened on click of child links

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am building a small profile box containing some detail of person along with profile pic with link to profile page.

I am opening a modal window when user clicks on the profile box. The modal window is creating problem. Whenever I am trying to click on profile pic which is inside a profile box, it's opening modal window instead of going to profile page. This is happening because I think the logic to open modal window is bind with whole profile box.

Please see below image representing problem.

[image]

The code is present here: [jsBin link](http://jsbin.com/meduhume/1/watch)

The expected behaviour should be like whenever user clicks on profile pic(which is link) in profile box, it should not open a modal window instead of it, it should go to that link(in our case profile pic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) in profile pic event handler